# .dSYMファイルは何処にあるのでしょうか

Tags: swift, xcode

.dSYMファイルは何処にあるのでしょうか

サイトを巡って、以下にあるような記載を見つけました。
/Users/[ユーザー名]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[プロジェクト名]-[ランダムな文字列]/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/[プロジェクト名].app.dSYM
上記ディレクトリには下記のファイルはあるようなのですが、dSYMが見つからない状態です。
[プロジェクト名].app
[プロジェクト名].swiftmodule

Answer (score 1):

Xcodeの
`Build Settings`＞`Build Options`＞`Debug Information Format`
の設定はどうなっていますか？
「`DWARF with dSYM File`」以外にチェックが入っていませんか？
dSYMを無効にするとビルドは早くなりますがdSYMは生成されません。
また、ビルドしなおすと前のdSYMは削除されます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！
「DWARF」になっておりました。早速試させていただきます！